# how to get all options values of simple hierarchical select in drupal $form?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms, taxonomy-terms

i have writed this code to unset empty terms :

```
    function shs_selective_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-projet-immobilier-page-1') {            
    foreach ($form['field_r_t_tid']['#options'] as $tid => $term_name) {
      if (is_numeric($tid)) {
        $result_count = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
        ->fields('ti')
        ->condition('ti.tid', $tid, '=')
        ->execute()
        ->rowCount();

        // Removing the option for tags with no-content
        if (!$result_count) {
          unset($form['field_r_t_tid']['#options'][$tid]);
        }                
      }
    }

  }
}
```

but is not worked, he show me this error : Undefined index : #options ...
how can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 you can use [field_info_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7), while in Drupal 6 you can use [content_field_instance_read()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content_crud.inc/function/content_field_instance_read/5), which is defined in the CCK module.

You can also use [list_allowed_values()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!list!list.module/function/list_allowed_values/7).

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$allowed_values = list_allowed_values($field);
```

Comment: is not working, i tried this class but it the same problem

Comment: Maybe you should provide more informations than "Not working", I'm currently using those methods to get each values of select-fields onto my Drupal websites ^^'

Comment: the only errors that it show for me is :"Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", and when i use dsm($form); i found only those result 
$form['field_name']['#type'],
$form['field_name']['#attributes']
$form['field_name']['#default_value]

Comment: <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-r-t-tid shs-wrapper-processed">
 <input class="element-invisible shs-enabled form-text shs-processed" type="text" id="edit-field-r-t-tid" name="field_r_t_tid" value="All" size="60" maxlength="128">
<select id="edit-field-r-t-tid-select-1" class="shs-select form-select shs-select-level-1" style="display: inline-block;"><option value="0">- Aucun(e) -</option> <option value="526">Kebili (0)</option><option value="523">Mahdia (0)</option> </select></div>

Comment: i think is not the same select field that you use, i using a simple hierarchical select field, he has a different architecture